# Changing Color Scheme Automatically?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, image-sprite

Here's my image:

[image]

I'm wondering if it's possible to automatically change all the images to using a color scheme close to #489fdc.  I've tried making changes in Paint.NET and Photoshop, but haven't had any luck.  Does anyone have experience with doing this?

I only have the .png version and not a .psd - otherwise this would of course be easy :)

Comment: For future readers that come across this question: if you're using something like SVG or some other web based code, you can use a preprocessor like SASS or LESS to use variable names and change the color scheme easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a layer above, fill it with the color of your choice. Blend mode color or hue. You can use a layer mask and get in real close at that point if you want to keep parts of elements their original color.

To make it transparent just ctrl-click on the layer with the elements to get all the good bits selected. Then you want to click on the layer with your color and hit the mask button!

[image]

E: the png

[image]